# Use string to call function without eval()

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a string to a function that then will use this string as a callback.
e.g.

```
app.on('notice', function(data) {

    var callback = data.func; // this is a string
    eval(callback + "()"); // trun string into an executable function

});
```

However I'm using this in an environment which prevents `eval()` from being used... How can I rewrite this to work without eval?

I've tried:

```
var self = this; 
return function(){ self[callback]() };
```

*But it doesn't call the function (and I don't get any errors)*

Update: I forgot I also need to handle parameters:

e.g.

```
var params = ['param1', 'param2'];

eval(callback + "("+ params +")");
```

Comment: Need more context. Where is the function you are trying to call located and what does data.func hold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `window` object.
Replace your `eval()` call with :

```
window[callback]();
```

Comment: @epascarello: If it weren't, `eval(callback + "()");` wouldn't work, either.

Comment: Thanks, what about if I had params? See my updated question. As this doesn't seem to work: `window[callback](params);`

Comment: window[callback].apply(window, params);

Comment: Gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined ` when I try and do that...

Comment: In fact `window[callback]();` doesn't work either... but `eval(callback + "()");` does...

Comment: @Cameron: that means a function with that name is in scope, but not global scope.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor .

```
var func = new Function("console.log('i am a new function')");
func();
```

Comment: You might as well `eval()` it, then.

Comment: The op states that he cannot use `eval()`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your answer is basically the same as using `eval`.

Comment: well , maybe the op's environment allows use of Function constructor, but not `eval()` .

Comment: And how do I make the callback the name of the function?

Comment: @Cerbrus  Sorry for the two year old comment. But eval would well evaluate the expression immediately... this allows us to wait for some condition to happen and then to run function. I can see an use case here and there for this.