# how to perform aggregation and expression from given string (formula)?

Tags: javascript

I want to do aggregation operation by identifying "sum(a)" as in the below string and need to perform some logical operation to get sum, avg, count or percentage(i have separate method to do that so don't worry about that).

expression like below,

```
 = '"sum(a)" * 10 + "count(b)"'
```

Here a and b is key word. Based on the key word i will perform the operation. But i need to identify operation name and key word in the above string.

Then, I need to execute the expression without using `eval` function for following expression. like below,

"10 * 10 + 22"

Note: I am trying to use Function constructor, but i am facing performance issue.([Use string to call function without eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424514/use-string-to-call-function-without-eval/26424563))

Comment: where are count and sum?

Comment: @LaxmikantDange probably written down in the rest of the homework assignment?

Comment: @Andreas It is maybe more than simply a `for`loop. You have to parse the expression

Comment: What you need to do is to build a *parser*. You can use regular expressions to **validate** the lines, but you will need write the rest of the code yourself. Regular expressions do not cater for this.

Comment: Souldn't the whole expression be a string? Shouldn't it be `'sum(a) * 10 + count(a)'`

Comment: `without using eval` also I assume without `new Function` too?.. If it's without `new Function` also, you will need to parse.  There are lots of JS parsers out there, an example one would be peg.js.  https://pegjs.org/

Comment: @C.Champagne yes expression be a string. i have modified my post. I hope it now clear

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum(values){
  return values.reduce(function(s, n){
  return s + n;
}, 0)
}

function count(values){
  return values.length
}

alert( sum([2,3,4]) * 10 + count([2,3,4]) )
```

Comment: My bad.! Kind of mixed that with the sum ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.proptotype.reduce`:

```js
const values = [2,3,4];
const sum = values.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);
console.log(sum * 10 + values.length);
```